# log4net custom appender message format is ignored

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-appender

I have implemented a custom appender by inheriting from AppenderSkeleton. My logger instance is created correctly and when logging the 'Append' method is called but the message is not formatted correctly. I have tried a couple of different ways by passing a StreamWriter instance, but all calls to it fails to write to the stream. The other thing I've tried is using the RenderedMessage property but the value returned is the exact message without the layout formatting.

```
protected override void Append(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
    StreamWriter _writer = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream());
    RenderLoggingEvent(_writer, loggingEvent);
    //After writing the logging event the base stream position remains 0
    byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[_writer.BaseStream.Position];
    _writer.BaseStream.Read(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);

    //Also trying to read from a stream reader created from the base stream fails
    var reader = new StreamReader(_writer.BaseStream);
    var test = reader.ReadToEnd();

    //variable test is not formatted correctly according to the conversion pattern
    test = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage;
}

<appender name="TestAppender" type="log4netTestApp">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="[%date]-[%thread]-[%level]-[%logger] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Changing from a memory stream to file stream has the correct layout, so it must be something with using a memory stream.

Comment: have you consulted with the `log4net` reference guide I am quite sure it gives numerous examples on how to configue the appender

Comment: Your problem is you are writing to a MemoryStream which is then not accessed

Comment: I've updated it with the attempted read from the base stream but the position is never incremented.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I needed to flush the _writer. Once that was done I got the correct stream position and all the formatting was present.